# Merge 2 relational dataframes to nested JSON / dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have another problem with joining to dataframes using pandas. I want to merge a complete dataframe into a column/field of another dataframe where the foreign key field of DF2 matches the unique key of DF1.

The input data are 2 CSV files roughly looking likes this:

**CSV 1 / DF 1:**

```
cid;name;surname;address
1;Mueller;Hans;42553
2;Meier;Peter;42873
3;Schmidt;Micha;42567
4;Pauli;Ulli;98790
5;Dick;Franz;45632
```

**CSV 2 / DF 1:**

```
OID;ticketid;XID;message
1;9;1;fgsgfs
2;8;2;gdfg
3;7;3;gfsfgfg
4;6;4;fgsfdgfd
5;5;5;dgsgd
6;4;5;dfgsgdf
7;3;1;dfgdhfd
8;2;2;dfdghgdh
```

I want each row of DF2, which XID matches with a cid of DF1, as a single field in DF1. my final goal is to convert the above input files into a nested JSON format.

Edit 1:

Something like this:

```
    [
      {
        "cid": 1,
        "name": "Mueller",
        "surname": "Hans",
        "address": 42553,
        "ticket" :[{
                   "OID": 1,
                   "ticketid": 9,
                   "XID": 1,
                   "message": "fgsgfs"
                   }]
      },
    ...]
```

Edit 2:

Some further thoughts: Would it be possible to create a dictionary of each row in dataframe 2 and then append this dictionary to a new column in dataframe 1 where some value (xid) of the dictionary matches with a unique id in a row (cid) ?

Some pseudo code I have in my mind:

```
Add new column "ticket" in DF1
Iterate over rows in DF2:
    row to dictionary
    iterate over DF1
        find row where cid = dict.XID
            append dictionary to field in "ticket"
convert DF1 to JSON
```

Non Python solution are also acceptable.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the expected result?

Comment: My final goal is basically a nested json where the data from CSV 2 is the child object. I will update an example output shortly.

Comment: Shouldn't you have 2 tickets (XID = 1) in your example output?

Comment: You're right. I will change this. I created sample input/output seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect as output but check [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on="cid", right_on="XID", how="left")
```

---

[EDIT based on the expected output]

Maybe something like this:

```
(
    df1.merge(
        df2.groupby("XID").apply(lambda g: g.to_dict(orient="records")).reset_index(name="ticket"), 
        how="left", left_on="cid", right_on="XID")
    .drop(["XID"], axis=1)
    .to_json(orient="records")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this doesn't give me the desired output. I'm aware of basic merging and joining, but I need the complete df2 in a column of the output dataframe.